# Liferay admin page server error

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

On trying to access the site admin for an almost brand new new install of liferay, I get:

```
Internal Server Error
An error occurred while accessing the requested resource. 
http://10.1.30.63:8080/group/control_panel?refererPlid=20632&controlPanelCategory=current_site&doAsGroupId=20181&p_p_id=156
```

and in the logs:

```
Sep 21, 2015 4:50:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/liferay/marketplace/util/PortletPropsValues
        at com.liferay.marketplace.store.portlet.StoreControlPanelEntry.hasAccessPermission(StoreControlPanelEntry.java:33)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor857.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy414.hasAccessPermission(Unknown Source)
---snip---
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It looks like some problem with the marketplace, but I haven't touched that on this install. 
the problem occurs without anything added to the system, (my portlet is deployed, but not running)

Comment: crossposted in https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/59543832

Answer (score -1):

You can directly replace the  markert-portlet in webapps, and restart the server.